# S3 virtual-host style nginx configuration for subdomains

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, virtualhost, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to get a min.io server up and running with virtual-host style and am failing to configure nginx to do so correctly.

**Expected result**

bucket.s3.domain.com works to access bucket

**Actual result**

bucket.s3.domain.com is redirected to s3.domain.com/bucket – this does not generate virtual host style URLs.

My config (I omitted default port 80 to 443 redirect and other not relevant docker containers):

```
     http {
         upstream minio-s3 {
      server 127.0.0.1:9000;

     }

server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/privkey.pem;
server_name s3.domain.com;
location / {
proxy_pass http://minio-s3;
```

}

}

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/privkey.pem;
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+).s3.domain.com";
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/$subdomain$request_uri;
proxy_set_header Host s3.domain.com;
```

}

}

**Notes**

Nginx running on Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04 (no Docker)
Min.io running on Docker port 9000

MINIO_DOMAIN is correctly set to s3.domain.com
bucket subdomain is correctly set
wildcard certificate for *.s3.domain.com is configured

**Questions**

- How can I configure Min.io (besides passing env MINIO_DOMAIN) to use virtual host style URLs together with nginx?
- How can I set up nginx to support this case?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer to my original question is pretty simple:

Only one server block is needed, the subdomain regex is added to the server name and min.io resolves this correctly

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/s3.domain.com/privkey.pem;
server_name "~^(?<subdomain>[^.]+).s3.domain.com" s3.domain.com;
location / {
proxy_pass http://minio-s3;
```

I hope this helps someone struggling with the same.
Virtual host in in short with Min.io:

1. Register domain, subdomain (per bucket)
2. Point domains all to your server (CNAME etc.)
3. Generate certificates with certbot (domain, wildcard for subdomains)
4. Launch min.io passing MINIO_DOMAIN as environment variable
5. Point all domains to Min.io application (domain and subdomains)